# Can anyone help me be able to design the title page Master thesis?

Tags: graphics, titles

I use this template, but I want some of the changes it as shown in the picture

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{bth}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{changepage}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}
{\pagestyle{empty}
\changepage{5cm}{1cm}{-0.5cm}{-0.5cm}{}{-2cm}{}{}{}
\noindent%   
{\small
\begin{tabular}{p{0.75\textwidth} p{0.25\textwidth}}
\textit{Republic of Iraq}&\multirow{4}{*}{\bthcsnotextlogo{3cm}}\\
\textit{Ministry of Higher Education}\\
\textit{Scientific Research}\\
\textit{University of Babylon}\\
\textit{College of Education for Pure Sciences}\\
\textit{Department of Mathematics}\\
\end{tabular}}

\begin{center}

\par\vspace {4cm}

{\huge\textbf{SPECIAL NUMBERS IN GRAPH THEORY\\*[0.25cm]}}   

\par\vspace {2cm}

{\Large\textbf{Research}}                   
\par\vspace {1cm}

{\textbf{Submitted to the council of the College of Education for Pure Sciences of University of Babylon in Partial Fulfillment of the Requirements for the Degree of Higher Diploma in Mathematical Sciences}}                   
\par\vspace {1cm}
{\Large\textbf{BY}}                   
\par\vspace {1cm}
{\Large\textbf{Ayad Jassim Mohammed}}                   
\par\vspace {1cm}
{\Large\textbf{Supervised by}}
\par\vspace {1cm}
{\Large\textbf{Assist.prof. Ahmed A. Omran}}
\par\vspace {2cm}

\end{center}

\noindent%
{\small 2016 A.D ...... . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . , , , , , , ,  . . . . . . . . . . . . .... 1437 A.H. \\

\noindent%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Can I make this template as in the picture with a change, and is there a better and easier template

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question? Please edit your previous questions instead of posting the same question again.

Comment: Your code got a little bit messed up, so I am guessing: Are you looking for `\hfill`? Maybe try `\noindent{\small 2016 A.D \hfill 1437 A.H.}`

Comment: Thanks @Flinston this has been successful>>\noindent{\small 2016 A.D \hfill 1437 A.H.}
2-I need to add the university logo ... as in the picture

Comment: `\textit{Department of Mathematics}\\
\end{tabular}}\hfill\includegraphics{logoFilename}` Remove the second column of the table.

Comment: Many templates are difficult. Use [a very simple template](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports).

Comment: Check out `butterfly` [here](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/titlepageExamples).